# Node-red not starting

Tags: port, beagleboneblack, node-red

I'm trying to start the 'node-red' on BeagleboneBlack, but the application only returns this error:

```
24 May 20:15:53 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.16.2
24 May 20:15:53 - [info] Node.js  version: v4.8.0
24 May 20:15:53 - [info] Linux 4.4.54-ti-r93 arm LE
24 May 20:15:56 - [info] Loading palette nodes
24 May 20:16:14 - [warn] ---------------------------------------------------          
---
24 May 20:16:14 - [warn] [rpi-gpio] Info : Ignoring Raspberry Pi specific  
node
24 May 20:16:14 - [warn] [upm-grove-button] Error: Module version mismatch. 
Expected 46, got 14.
24 May 20:16:14 - [warn] [upm-grove-buzzer] Error: Module version mismatch. 
Expected 46, got 14.
24 May 20:16:14 - [warn] [upm-grove-led] Error: Module version mismatch. 
Expected 46, got 14.
24 May 20:16:14 - [warn] [upm-grove-light] Error: Module version mismatch. 
Expected 46, got 14.
24 May 20:16:14 - [warn] [upm-grove-relay] Error: Module version mismatch. 
Expected 46, got 14.
24 May 20:16:14 - [warn] [upm-grove-rgb-lcd] Error: Module version mismatch. 
Expected 46, got 14.
24 May 20:16:14 - [warn] [upm-grove-rotary] Error: Module version mismatch. 
Expected 46, got 14.
24 May 20:16:14 - [warn] [upm-grove-sound] Error: Module version mismatch. 
Expected 46, got 14.
24 May 20:16:14 - [warn] [upm-grove-temperature] Error: Module version 
mismatch. Expected 46, got 14.
24 May 20:16:14 - [warn] [upm-grove-adxl345] Error: Module version mismatch. 
Expected 46, got 14.
24 May 20:16:14 - [warn] [upm-grove-servo] Error: Module version mismatch. 
Expected 46, got 14.
24 May 20:16:14 - [warn] ---------------------------------------------------
---
24 May 20:16:14 - [info] Settings file  : /root/.node-red/settings.js
24 May 20:16:14 - [info] User directory : /root/.node-red
24 May 20:16:14 - [info] Flows file     : /root/.node-
red/flows_beaglebone.json
24 May 20:16:14 - [info] Creating new flow file
24 May 20:16:14 - [info] Starting flows
24 May 20:16:15 - [info] Started flows
24 May 20:16:15 - [warn] Communication server error: Error: listen 
EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:1880
24 May 20:16:15 - [error] Unable to listen on http://127.0.0.1:1880/
24 May 20:16:15 - [error] Error: port in use
```

I already tried to reinstall the packages, but the error persists. Please, help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Error: port in use` error indicates you already have a process using port 1880.

It is likely you already have Node-RED running on your BeagleBoneBlack. You can check this by running:

```
ps -ef | grep node-red
```

or

```
ps -ef | grep red.js
```

depending on how it is running. The output will show if there is already a node-red process running.

How you stop it will depend on how it has been run. Check the documentation to see how it has been setup to run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the port 1880 is in use. Check if the 'Node-Red' is active with:

> **ps -ef | grep node-red**

To stop the active process, run:

> **node-red-stop**